# Anyway to clear cache on Drupal 7 without any extra modules or even going to the performance page?

Tags: 7, caching

I'm looking for a way to clear cache easily without installing any fancy modules or going to the performance page. Is there a URL I can just visit to clear the cache? Basically try to find the shortest and fastest way to clear cache without much effort.

Comment: tried [drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush)?

Comment: Where are your cache bins?

Answer (score 3):

`drush cc all` is the safest bet.

Visiting www.example.com/update.php will also clear the caches, but you need to be logged in.  Otherwise, this is a DOS vector.

Comment: **PS:** you need to install drush on your server first. Then on your console, make sure you're inside the Drupal directory before doing your drush commands.

Comment: With properly defined site aliases, you don't need to be in the right directory, and with ssh/remote aliases, you can run drush on your local machine and do most things remotely.